# python csv register_dialect

Tags: python, csv

I am using the csv module in python to parse a delimieted file. I use the register_dialect method of csv to specify the deleimiter and other parameters. It was working fine all this while, but now I have a file that uses 'tab' as delimiter. This obviously gives me an error - "TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string" on using '\t' as the delimiter. 
Is there a way to be able to use the tab character here? What are my options now?

Thanks!!

```
fileObject = open(fullFilePath,'rb')
csv.register_dialect('MyDialect', delimiter='\t',doublequote=False,quotechar='',lineterminator='\n',escapechar='',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
myReader = csv.reader(fileObject,'MyDialect')
```

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Could you post some code? because csv.register_dialect('foo', delimiter='\t') works just fine for me... Also could you tell us which version of python you are using? thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to run fine.. http://ideone.com/nPzwy

Comment: Make sure your code has `'\t'` and not `r'\t'` or `'\\t'`. A surefire way to generate one tab character is `chr(9)`.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, when i added \t as is it worked fine,but actually it was coming from a variable, so something was chaning on the way. On using the ascii character, it worked fine. Thanks again all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the default dialect `excel_tab`. You can specify it in `csv.reader` calls with `dialect=excel_tab`, which will replace the default `dialect=excel` which uses CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a `register_dialect` method but one can pass in a `csv.reader` has a `delimiter` argument that accepts a value of `\t`. http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have editied my original post with the code I am using.